# typescript infer prop type from type of other property

Tags: javascript, typescript

```js
interface featureType<Props=any, State=any> {
  initialState: State;
  props: Props;
  processState: (props: Props, state: State) => any;
}

const feature1Comp: featureType = {
  initialState: { lastName: '' },
  props: { firstName: 'eliav' },
  processState: (props, state) => {
    props; // type should be {firstName: string} but instead is any
  },
};
```

why `props` type is not being inferred? what am I missing?

[quick playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAhhOYCuUIBUCeADhADwAKUA9oQM4C8cI%20ANMgMpgYQNMB8yAbwCwAKGTJQwMMDgAbDlwBc7TpADco8YSq1lFajQ1jk2ykho0FkZQApTu5PtqsaqiMqsQAlMjr9G%20EYAvqKiCJQgrqjoWDgAjADClAC2hMpoGNh4RCh0gpoSIFIy8m7KAsiycK4AcnDJ7sgA5E3IQcwF9jTlqMBQtfWNTRCyMgBure2dVOaWZch2OjQu865QoADmPn75xlpLasgA9EfIYDnINAAWlJiyACbIAEYoAjB9Aw3Ka5tBz5hgQqudCPYA0ZABApTERBNRAA)(the URL is being cut so copy-paste the code)

(I post this question only because it takes too much time to find a solution for that issue and this is quite a common usage for typescript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Capitalize your types and interfaces (FeatureType) - that's a convention
2. If you use generics, you should provide them to your type definiton:

`const feature1Comp = FeatureType<{ firstName: string}, any>`

Treat generics as a kind of 'type functions'. If you don't provide the concrete types, defaults will be used, so TS assumes Props and State are typed as any.

Update: here is what will work with infering

```
interface Component<P,S> {
    initialState: S,
    props: P,
    processState: (props: P, state: S) => any
}

function createComponent<P, S>(arg: Component<P, S>): Component<P, S> {
    return arg;
}

const x = createComponent({
    initialState: 'someValue',
    props: { firstName: 'Elias' },
    processState: (p, s) => {
        console.log(p.firstName) // Works
        console.log(p.lastName) // Error
    }
})
```

Comment: thanks but this is not solving my use case, I want typescript to infer the type rather then writing it manually

Comment: By using `const x: featureType` you're forcing the type to use the declared default for the type argument, though, which is `any`. This prevents inference, because you're explicitly telling the compiler not to infer. Just don't declare the type of the variable at all.

Comment: @IngoBürk so how does the compiler would know he should infer the desired prop type from another type?

Comment: Right, sorry you can't just omit the type. You need to specify the type arguments here as Roman said.

Comment: If you want to get this to work without specifying the type arguments, you could create helper functions that allow inference to work by first specifying initialState/props and then processState in a second step. But you wouldn't just create the object as a literal in one go.

Comment: could you please provide working code (without required types arguments) as an answer?

Comment: @EliavLouski see the update

Comment: I deleted my answer again since the update here is significantly better than my answer. :-)

Comment: this is a good answer, thank you! yet still not perfect as this have runtime implications, this is the best typescript can do? there is no way statically infer the type by typescript ? if no -  I will accept this answer

Comment: I don't know as I prefer implicit typing. And surprise, it works in flow :)

Comment: I know! in my next project I definitely going to give flow a decent try. thanks

Comment: FWIW, there's probably a good chance a decent JS engine will inline this function anyway.